# GEE errors about bands

Tags: google-earth-engine

Here is my complete code. I face this error: ConfusionMatrix (Error)
Output of image computation is too large (21 bands for 1048576 pixels = 160.0 MiB > 80.0 MiB).If this is a reduction, try specifying a larger 'tileScale' parameter.

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);

var l7 = landsat
.filterBounds(table)
.filterDate('2002-01-01','2003-01-01')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',10))
function applyScaleFactors(img) {
  var ms = img.select('SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B7').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
  var tir = img.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0).clip(table);
  return img
    .addBands(ms, null, true)
    .addBands(tir, null, true)
}

var l7 = landsat
  .filterBounds(table)
  .filterDate('2002-01-01', '2003-01-01')
  .map(applyScaleFactors)
  .map(function(img) {
    var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B4']).rename('ndvi')
    var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B1', 'SR_B7']).rename('ndwi')
    return img.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndwi)
      .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end']);
  })
  .median()
  .clip(table)
  
var modis = modis_lulc
.filterDate('2002-01-01','2003-01-01')
.filterBounds(table)
.select('LC_Type2')
.toBands()
.clip(table);



Map.addLayer(l7,[],'landsat_composite',false);


var vis = {min: 0, max:15, palette:['1c0dff', '05450a', '086a10', '54a708', '78d203',
  '009900','c6b044','dcd159','dade48','fbff13','b6ff05','27ff87',
  'c24f44', 'a5a5a5', 'ff6d4c','f9ffa4']};

Map.addLayer(modis,vis,'modis_lulc',false);


var cross = ee.Image.cat([l7,modis]);

print(cross)


var training = cross.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 300,
  classBand: '2002_01_01_LC_Type2',
  region: table,
  scale: 30
});





var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(80)
    .train({
      features: training,
      classProperty: '2002_01_01_LC_Type2',
      inputProperties: ['SR_B1','SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B7','ndvi', 'ndwi']
    });



var classified = l7.classify(classifier);

Map.addLayer(classified,vis,'landsat_lulc',false);


var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Confusion matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Training kappa coefficient: ', trainAccuracy.kappa());




// new accuracy assessment

var training = cross.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 100,
  classBand: '2002_01_01_LC_Type2',
  region: table,
  scale: 30,
  seed: 1
});

var validated = training.classify(classifier);

print(validated)


var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('2002_01_01_LC_Type2', 'classification');
print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy);
print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Validation kappa coefficient: ', testAccuracy.kappa());

Export.image.toDrive({image:classified,description:'landCover2010',scale:15,region:table})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your script. For starters, the error you see, `ms is not defined`, is a very accurate error message and completely describes the problem. You're using `ms` in your second function without defining it. You want to be using `img` instead.

In addition to this, you use the wrong band name for `tir`. It should be `ST_B6`.

Other improvements you should consider:

- Only `clip()` the final resulting image. It's a quite costly operation, and this will make your script more efficient.
- Use `ee.ImageCollection.filterBounds()` to reduce the number of images in the collection you map.
- Use `ee.ImageCollection.filterDate()`, to limit the dates of the imagery to include in your composite.
- You probably also want to mask out clouds.

Altogether, excluding the cloud masking, it could look something like this:

```
function applyScaleFactors(img) {
  var ms = img.select('SR_B1', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B7').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
  var tir = img.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0).clip(table);
  return img
    .addBands(ms, null, true)
    .addBands(tir, null, true)
}

var l7 = landsat
  .filterBounds(table)
  .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2001-01-01')
  .map(applyScaleFactors)
  .map(function(img) {
    var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B4']).rename('ndvi')
    var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B1', 'SR_B7']).rename('ndwi')
    return img.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndwi)
      .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end']);
  })
  .median()
  .clip(table)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/45eb4fac1d2b86df504730cb391dd9be

Comment: I dit what you say. But there is an error. ConfusionMatrix (Error)
Output of image computation is too large (21 bands for 1048576 pixels = 160.0 MiB > 80.0 MiB).
If this is a reduction, try specifying a larger 'tileScale' parameter.

Comment: I wrote again my code in the question. would you please consider it Daniel?

Comment: That’s a completely different question. Make a new one.

Comment: OK Daniel. I ask in another question. Thanks.